# WooCommerce get_weight hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Is there any hook to WooCommerce get_weight() like below. It seems like there - But it's not working

```
// define the <get_hook_prefix>weight callback 

function filter_get_hook_prefix_weight( $this_weight, $instance ) { 
$this_weight = 10;
return $this_weight; 
}
// add the filter 
add_filter( "woocommerce_data_get_weight", 'filter_get_hook_prefix_weight', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// define the <get_hook_prefix>weight callback 
function filter_get_hook_prefix_weight( $this_weight, $instance ) { 
$this_weight = 10;
return $this_weight; 
}
// add the filter 
add_filter( "woocommerce_product_get_weight", 'filter_get_hook_prefix_weight', 10, 2 );
```

Try this